# WebDriver: set initial URL

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I use WebDriver Java bindings. Creating a FirefoxDriver instance launches the Firefox browser with the 'firstrun' page: https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/42.0/firstrun/learnmore/ . It takes some time to load this page.

I want Firefox to start from "about:blank" to make the initialization faster. For Internet Explorer this can be done by:

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INITIAL_BROWSER_URL, "about:blank");
new InternetExplorerDriver(cap);
```

How to do the same for Firefox and Chrome?

Comment: Have you explored setting a profile in FF?

Comment: The question is about launching an FF instance with WebDriver, which launches a Firefox with default settings. It doesn't (and shouldn't) use a preset profile, so it is certainly a valid question how to adjust those default settings.

Answer (score 2):

#### Firefox:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("browser.startup.homepage", "about:blank");
profile.setPreference("startup.homepage_welcome_url", "about:blank");
profile.setPreference("startup.homepage_welcome_url.additional", "about:blank");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Comment: I'm very late, but exactly where would you put this code?

Comment: Into the place where you initialize your WebDriver instance. If you use jUnit, this may be in the @Before method.

Comment: What about for the Chrome?